# Why array can store more data than it should?

Tags: c

The following C code has **char str[3];** and it's supposed to only store 3 char right?

However, when I compile and run the program, it seems like it can store more than that.

I only get the "Segmentation fault" error when I entered "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY" which is clearly more than 3 char.

May I know why?

p/s: Yeah, I know "gets" function is dangerous and not recommended to use. I'm just curious why it can keep more data than it should.

```
user@box:~/c$ cat -n putsgets.c 
     1  #include <stdio.h>
     2
     3  int main()
     4  {
     5          char str[3];
     6          puts("Enter a line of text: ");
     7          gets(str);
     8          puts("\nYou entered: ");
     9          puts(str);
    10          return 0;
    11  }
user@box:~/c$ 
user@box:~/c$ gcc putsgets.c -o putsgets
putsgets.c: In function ‘main’:
putsgets.c:7:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  gets(str);
  ^~~~
/tmp/cclFmZp2.o: In function `main':
putsgets.c:(.text+0x1f): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
user@box:~/c$ 
user@box:~/c$ ./putsgets 
Enter a line of text: 
ABC

You entered: 
ABC
user@box:~/c$ ./putsgets 
Enter a line of text: 
ABCD    

You entered: 
ABCD
user@box:~/c$
```

Next

```
user@box:~/c$ ./putsgets 
Enter a line of text: 
ABCDE     

You entered: 
ABCDE
user@box:~/c$ ./putsgets 
Enter a line of text: 
ABCDE

You entered: 
ABCDE
user@box:~/c$ ./putsgets 
Enter a line of text: 
ABCDEF

You entered: 
ABCDEF

user@box:~/c$ ./putsgets 
Enter a line of text: 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN

You entered: 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
```

Finally, Segmentation fault error occurred when I entered ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY (last line)

```
user@box:~/c$ ./putsgets 
Enter a line of text: 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU

You entered: 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
user@box:~/c$ ./putsgets 
Enter a line of text: 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

You entered: 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Segmentation fault
user@box:~/c$ ./putsgets 
Enter a line of text: 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY   

You entered: 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
Segmentation fault
user@box:~/c$
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior. It might crash or not.

Comment: That why `gets()` is not anymore in the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you can add more cbaracters to an array than declared, because no runtime checks are performed. What you do is  called buffer overrun.

If such code accepts data over a network connection, then a hacker could exploit this to run arbitrary machine code!

However, in java and C# runtime checks are performed and a buffer overrun causes a OutOfRangeExeption.  These checks are performed by the java virtual machine.

Good question and keep up your curiousity.

Answer (score 5):

As you likely know, C does not check for memory safety. Utilities such as valgrind can really help with that, though.

Your operating system is giving your program a bit more memory than it requested, and it only finds segmentation faults when you go outside one of that memory.

[How does a segmentation fault work internally (kernel/hardware)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936534/how-does-a-segmentation-fault-work-internally-kernel-hardware)

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behaviour because C and C++ does not check array bound.